# "unorthodox" vs "heterodox"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

What's the difference between "unorthodox" and "heterodox"?

The dictionary I use roughly states that "heterodox" means "not orthodox", and "unorthodox" means well, "not orthodox".

Are they perfect synonyms?

Comment: Could you add what you found in a dictionary or two? That saves others repeating your own research.

Comment: They seem to be synonyms, but _unorthodox_ has been much more common since the 1920's. See the Ngram.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term *unorthodox* is used of things which do not adhere to “orthodoxy” but are not necessarily in opposition to it: “An unorthodox solution to the problem”. But I’ve only ever seen the term *heterodox* used for matters which oppose orthodoxy: “A heterodox sect”.

Also, as indicated by the examples I’ve given, *unorthodox* is usually contrasted to a figurative orthodoxy, a norm; *heterodox* is most commonly used in contrast to a literal orthodox theology.

Comment: Do you mean that "heterodox" has a negative connotation?

Comment: Not necessarily, @Pacerier; though it often has a negative denotation: the _ortho_ in “orthodox” makes the claim that this is the One True Path.

Comment: @Pacerier Heterodox is opposite orthodox. Unorthodox is anything other than orthodox.

Answer (score 2):

To be UNorthodox is to **actively** go against orthodoxy. To be "heterodox" is to be "different" from orthodoxy. But this "difference" could be passive, rather than active.

Comment: Does [the other answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/183153/8278) directly contradicts yours?

Comment: Yes, @Pacerier, it does.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, So who is right?

Answer (score 1):

These are the definitions from the dictionary...

**unorthodox** - "contrary to what is usual, traditional, or accepted; not orthodox"

**heterodox** - "not conforming with accepted or orthodox standards or beliefs"

So, I have to agree with @Tom Au that unorthodox is to actively go against orthodoxy and heterodox is to be different from orthodoxy. Notice the word **contrary** in the definition of unorthodox.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. It would be great if you could provide links to your definitions.

Comment: [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heterodox) defines heterodox as: contrary to or different from an acknowledged standard

Comment: I'd think "conforming" is more significant than "contrary".  Not conforming implies not following the rules; deliberately going against what is required.  "Contrary" just means it's different. People sometimes do things in unorthodox ways (e.g. using a knife as a screwdriver), without denying the correctness of the orthodox way.

Answer (score 1):

'Doxy' is a greek root. 'Hetro' is a greek root. 'Un' has more germanic orgins.

Hetrodox is the combination of two greek roots, whereas unorthodox is a combination of a germanic and a greek root and was a bastardised form that developed overtime in English as Old English germanic forms became fused with Greek words that lacked equivalents.